# MySQL stored procedure to update a table and delete related

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Consider I have two tables `A` and `B` in a MySQL database which are related to each other:

```
create table A (
id int(11) not null auto_increment, 
name varchar(45),
is_archived TINYINT(1), 
create_date datetime)

create table B (
id int(11) not null auto_increment,
a_id int(11),
name varchar(45)
```

How can I have a store procedure to check items in Table A and if create_date is older than a value ( e. g. `DATEDIFF(NOW(), a.create_date) >30` ), update the item in table A as `a.is_archived =1` and then remove the items in table B which are related with this item .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your stored procedure will look something like :

```
//update table1
UPDATE A SET is_archived = 1 
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), create_date) >30

//remove from table2
UPDATE B INNER jOIN A 
ON A.id = B.a_id SET DELETED = 1 
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), a.create_date) >30
```

Or if you want to delete the rows from the table, substitute `UPDATE` with `DELETE`